docker nginx worker_processes directive is not allowed here in
I’m configuring Docker Nginx, but I keep encountering the following error:
nginx-1  | 2024/12/26 11:57:50 [emerg] 1#1: "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1

nginx-1  | nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1

What I’m doing:
I’m trying to set up Nginx with Docker, and my setup includes three files:

docker-compose.yml 
nginx/nginx.conf 
nginx/Dockerfile 
Here’s the code I’m working with:

docker-compose.yml:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volumes:/usr/src/app/_static
      - media_volumes:/usr/src/app/_media
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn daniel_blog.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volumes:/usr/src/app/_static
      - media_volumes:/usr/src/app/_media
      - ./:/usr/src/app/_media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:17.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volumes:
  media_volumes:

nginx/nginx.conf:

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Default location
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://daniel_blog;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/_static/;
    }

    # Media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/_media/;
    }
}

nginx/Dockerfile:
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d


The Problem:
I added worker_processes auto; at the top of my nginx.conf, but I keep getting the error:
nginx-1  | nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1
Even when I remove worker_processes auto;, the same error persists.
I’m confused because I thought worker_processes should work in nginx.conf.
From the error log, it seems the file /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf is causing the issue.
I believe this is being referenced because of the COPY instruction in my Dockerfile.

My Understanding (and Questions):
I’ve read that worker_processes should only be in the main Nginx configuration file, like /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, not in /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf.
Is this correct? If so, how should I adjust my nginx.conf and Dockerfile to fix this issue?
Since I’m following a book tutorial, I don’t fully understand why this error occurs. Can you help me understand why worker_processes is not allowed in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Move worker_processes to the Main Configuration File
Instead of putting worker_processes in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf, place it in the main nginx.conf file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) like below
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    # Default location
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://daniel_blog;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/_static/;
    }

    # Media files
    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/_media/;
    }
}

Update the Main nginx.conf
  user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Modify the Dockerfile
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

Rebuild Your Docker Container
docker-compose down
docker-compose up --build


The worker_processes directive should only be in the main Nginx configuration file (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
